# System.Data.SQLite 1.0.101 unable to load dll since last update

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms, system.data.sqlite

I have a `Xamarin Forms` project, in which I use the nuget package `System.Data.SQLite` (v1.0.101 last updated in 04/19/2016) and it was working well until some days ago.

Now I don't know if I have changed something that caused my app to crash, or if the last update of the package is the reason I cannot run it anymore.

I am trying to run a Windows Phone 8.1 (not Silverlight) app in debug mode and  x86 target on my local emulator.

The error I get is:

> Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be missing the native sqlite3 library. If you have, or can restore, the previous Nuget package, can you compare them to see if library has been moved or accidentally left out?

Comment: I don't think I can restore it, because the package version history in the nuget page have only one entry, which is the current one...

Comment: Alright. I am unfamiliar with WP. Can you somehow verify that the x86 (not x64) version of sqlite3.dll is in the proper location on the emulator?